# minimax algorithm in javaScript is not working as expected and returns the wrong move

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I'm trying to make a Tic-Tac-Toe in javaScript using minimax algorithm but it seems that I'm doing something wrong and minimax algorithm, is not detecting the best move. Here is the code:

```
const board = ["X", null, null, null, null, "X", "X", "O", "O"];
/*
    X   _   _
    _   _   X
    X   O   O

*/

// duplicate passed board and return the new board state
const makeAIMove = (currentBoard, square, player) => {
    const nextBoard = [...currentBoard];
    nextBoard[square] = player;
    return nextBoard;
};

// find empty squares
const emptySquares = (sqBoard) =>
    sqBoard
        .map((sq, idx) => (sq === null ? idx : null))
        .filter((sq) => sq !== null);

// check if no empty squares are available
const isFinished = (sqBoard) => (emptySquares(sqBoard).length ? false : true);

// check winner
const checkWinner = (sqBoard) => {
    const winConditions = [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 3, 6],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],
        [0, 4, 8],
        [2, 4, 6],
    ];

    for (const winCondition of winConditions) {
        [a, b, c] = winCondition;
        if (sqBoard[a] && sqBoard[a] === sqBoard[b] && sqBoard[a] === sqBoard[c])
            return sqBoard[a];
    }

    return false;
};

// minimax algorithm
const minimax = (sqBoard, depth, isMaximizer) => {
    // terminal checker
    const theWinner = checkWinner(sqBoard);
    // we have a winner
    if (theWinner) {
        return theWinner === "X" ? -10 : 10;
    }
    // it's a tie
    if (isFinished(sqBoard)) {
        return 0;
    }

    let bestScore;
    if (isMaximizer) {
        bestScore = -1000;
        emptySquares(sqBoard).forEach((square) => {
            // make a sample move
            let nextBoard = makeAIMove(sqBoard, square, "O");

            // recursion
            let score = minimax(nextBoard, depth + 1, false);
            bestScore = Math.max(bestScore, score);
        });
    } else {
        bestScore = 1000;
        emptySquares(sqBoard).forEach((square) => {
            let nextBoard = makeAIMove(sqBoard, square, "X");
            let score = minimax(nextBoard, depth + 1, true);
            bestScore = Math.min(bestScore, score);
        });
    }
    return bestScore;
};

// find the best move
const nextBestMove = (sqBoard) => {
    let nextMoveArray = [];
    let remainedSquares = emptySquares(sqBoard);
    remainedSquares.forEach((square) => {
        let nextBoard = makeAIMove(sqBoard, square, "O");
        let theScore = minimax(nextBoard, 0, true);
        nextMoveArray.push({
            sq: square,
            sc: theScore,
        });
    });

    nextMoveSorted = nextMoveArray.sort((a, b) => (a.sc < b.sc ? 1 : -1));
    return nextMoveSorted[0].sq;
};

console.log(nextBestMove(board));
```

In the above condition, the best move would be stopping X to win by filling the board[3] with an "O" but it always detects another move that has a higher score.

Can anyone help me to understand what's going wrong with my code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code I understand that X is the minimizing and O the maximizing player. But then I see this code:

```
    let nextBoard = makeAIMove(sqBoard, square, "O");
    let theScore = minimax(nextBoard, 0, true);
```

So after O has moved, you call `minimax` with `isMaximizer` set to true. But this will make `minimax` play another O move, while O has already played. You want to get the best reply move for X, so you should pass `false` here:

```
    let theScore = minimax(nextBoard, 0, false);
```

Now, this will return -10 for every such call (so for every move of O), because the game is already in a lost state for O, whatever it does, X will win. If O moves at 3, then X will play 2 with a double attack.

If you want to differentiate between quick wins and slower wins, then you should adapt the score at each backtracking.

For instance, you could replace the `return bestScore` statement with a return of a value that is one unit closer to zero. So for example -10 becomes -9 and 5 becomes 4, and 0 remains 0:

```
    return bestScore - Math.sign(bestScore);
```

With this change, O will play at 3, as its score is -7 (still losing), while the other moves all score -9 (losing immediately with one move from X).

Comment: Brilliant! It took me at least three hours but I didn't notice that I'm passing "O" twice in a row to the code. Really appreciate your quick and helpful answer. That made my day.